# can not search for txt files android 6.0

Tags: java, android

**Recursive searching txt files in external storage** and put them in a listview. When the thread is running ,there should be a processdialog. It worked well on my phones(android 5.1 and android 4.4), but when I change to 6.0, it worked once and after that the dialog can not show. I persume that there is sth wrong with the storage path(**using Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();**).
  If I use the body memory as default, I get the path "/storage/emulated/0" and if I use the external storage as default, I get the path "/storage.164F-F6FD".The thread will also work but no files are load.

```
public class BookListActivity extends Activity {

private static List<String> file_name;
private static List<String> file_txt_path;
private MyBookAdapter adapter;
private File file;
private List<Map<String, String>> listItems;
private MultiModeCallback mCallback;
private String mExternalStoragePath;
private Handler mHandler;
private ListView mListView;
private ProgressDialog mProgressDialog;

/**
 * 接收返回的路径
 */
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    Log.d("com.ldgforever.jianreader", "receivingPath");
    if (data != null) {
        Log.d("com.ldgforever.jianreader", "onActivityResult");
        ArrayList<String> mPath = data.getStringArrayListExtra("file");
        for (int i = 0; i < mPath.size(); i++) {
            File pathFile = new File(mPath.get(i));
            Map<String, String> pathMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
            if (pathFile.exists()) {
                if (pathFile.getName().endsWith(".txt")) {
                    pathMap.put("Name", pathFile.getName());
                    pathMap.put("Path", pathFile.getPath());
                    listItems.add(pathMap);
                    savedataListMap.saveInfo(BookListActivity.this, "ListMap", listItems);
                    ShowTxtFilesInList(listItems);
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(BookListActivity.this, "请选择一个txt文件！", 0).show();
                    ;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle bundle) {
    super.onCreate(bundle);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_book_list);

    mProgressDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
    mProgressDialog.setCancelable(false);
    mProgressDialog.setMessage("正在搜索书籍，请稍候 ……");

    mExternalStoragePath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();
    Log.i("JianReader", mExternalStoragePath);
    file = new File(mExternalStoragePath);

    file_name = new ArrayList<String>();
    file_txt_path = new ArrayList<String>();
    listItems = new ArrayList<Map<String, String>>();

    listItems = savedataListMap.getInfo(BookListActivity.this, "ListMap");
    if (listItems.isEmpty()) {
        BookAddingDialog();
    } else {
        ShowTxtFilesInList(listItems);
    }

    mHandler = new Handler() {
        public void handleMessage(Message message) {
            switch (message.what) {
            case 12:
                Log.i("JianReader", message.what + "");
                ShowTxtFilesInList(listItems);
                savedataListMap.saveInfo(BookListActivity.this, "ListMap", listItems);
                if (mProgressDialog.isShowing()) {
                    mProgressDialog.dismiss();
                    return;
                }
                break;
            default:
                break;
            }
            return;
        }
    };
}

/**
 * 书籍添加对话框
 */
private void BookAddingDialog() {
    android.app.AlertDialog.Builder builder = new android.app.AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    builder.setTitle("请选择添加书籍的方式");
    builder.setPositiveButton("扫描SDCard添加", new android.content.DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialoginterface, int i) {
            listItems = new ArrayList<Map<String, String>>();
            mProgressDialog.show();
            new Thread() {
                public void run() {
                    listFileTxt(file);
                    mHandler.sendEmptyMessage(12);
                }
            }.start();
        }
    });
    builder.setNegativeButton("选择路径添加", new android.content.DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialoginterface, int i) {

            Intent intent = new Intent(BookListActivity.this, MyFileManager.class);
            startActivityForResult(intent, 2);
        }
    });
    builder.setNeutralButton("稍后手动添加", new android.content.DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialoginterface, int i) {
            dialoginterface.dismiss();
        }

    });
    builder.create().show();
}

/**
 * 将保存在List<Map<String,String>>中的书籍信息显示到ListView中
 * 
 * @param listItems
 */
private void ShowTxtFilesInList(final List<Map<String, String>> listItems) {
    if (file_name != null) {
        for (int i = 0; i < file_name.size(); i++) {
            HashMap<String, String> hashmap = new HashMap<String, String>();
            hashmap.put("Name", (String) file_name.get(i));
            hashmap.put("Path", (String) file_txt_path.get(i));
            listItems.add(hashmap);
        }
        adapter = new MyBookAdapter(this, listItems);
        mCallback = new MultiModeCallback();
        mListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.booklist);
        mListView.setChoiceMode(3); // Multi
        mListView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                Intent ii = new Intent(BookListActivity.this, ReadingActivity.class);
                String itemPath = listItems.get(position).get("Path");
                ii.putExtra("mItemPath", itemPath);
                startActivity(ii);
            }
        });
        mListView.setMultiChoiceModeListener(mCallback);
        mListView.setAdapter(adapter);
    } else {
        failAddingDialog();
        return;
    }
}

/**
 * 添加书籍失败对话框
 */
private void failAddingDialog() {
    android.app.AlertDialog.Builder builder = new android.app.AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    builder.setTitle("添加书籍失败");
    builder.setPositiveButton("确定", new android.content.DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialoginterface, int i) {
            dialoginterface.dismiss();
        }
    });
}

/**
 * 递归查找SD卡上所有书籍
 * 
 * @param file
 */
public static void listFileTxt(File file) {
    File[] files = file.listFiles();

    try {
        for (File f : files) {
            if (!f.isDirectory()) {
                if (f.getName().endsWith(".txt")) {
                    long size = f.length();
                    if (size > 50 * 1024) {
                        file_name.add(f.getName());
                        file_txt_path.add(f.getAbsolutePath());
                    }
                }
            } else if (f.isDirectory()) {
                listFileTxt(f);
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

ask for help

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32635704/android-permission-doesnt-work-even-if-i-have-declared-it

Comment: `If I use the body memory as default, I get the path "/storage/emulated/0" and if I use the external storage as default, I get the path "/storage.164F-F6FD"`. ?? `body memory` ? Please tell exactly how you retrieve both paths in code. And the latter will be ` "/storage/164F-F6FD"` i think.

Comment: Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();  then log.i

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Beginning in Android 6.0 (API level 23), users grant permissions to apps while the app is running, not when they install the app. This approach streamlines the app install process, since the user does not need to grant permissions when they install or update the app."

change it to

```
private void requestPermission(String permission){
    if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M){
        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(BookListActivity.this, 
                Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)
                        != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

                        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(BookListActivity.this,
                                new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE},
                                MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_READ_CONTACTS);

        }
    }
}
```

thanks the first comment
https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html